# zxing continuous scan works different the second time its used

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, zxing

I've used successfully the ContinuousScan from ZXing for xamarin using mvvmcross, I just press a button in one of my viewmodels and the camera show up. I used a delay between continuous scans I of 4000 to allow the user to read the barcodes at a slow pace. The first time  enter to the view model and enter to the scanner, everything works perfect. Then I press back and i have a list with the codes, I press back again and leave the view model. I enter again to the view model and open the scanner and it just barely has focus on a barcode and it scans it two or three times without waiting for the 4000ms delay that originally was set to it. What am i missing here?

```
public MvxCommand ObtainCommand()
    {
        return new MvxCommand(delegate
        {
            if (HandleScanResultEvent != null) HandleScanResultEvent(this, null);
            MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);
            var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
            scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
            scanner.TopText = Ts.TopTextScanContiniously;
            scanner.BottomText = Ts.BottomTextScan;

            var opt = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
            opt.DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 5000;

            //Start scanning
            scanner.ScanContinuously(opt, HandleScanResult);
        });
    }
```

The Handle result raise an event to the view model with the barcode read.

```
void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result r)
{
    if (r != null)
    {
        var opa = new OperationArgument
        {
            Operation = new Operation
            {
                Data  r.Text,
                Format = FromXingFormat(r.BarcodeFormat)
            }
        };

        if (DataObtained != null && !(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Text)))
        {
            DataObtained(this, opa);
        }
    }
}
```

the barcode scanner is opened via an mvxCommand assigned to the viewmodel. The posted code is in a class registered as a singleton.

Comment: Could you include your code that returns the list of scanned barcodes and the code that calls the code displayed?